# How to loop CardView based on API

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview, android-cardview, gson

I want my view like this, but this is still in hard code. I want my cardview looping based API

Comment: 'onResponse: received information:'  Is this log printed ? Means can you get the Response ?

Comment: yes i've done. but in my view doesnt show @AbhayKoradiya

Answer (score 0):

First, the UI problem is with the layout manager you use with your recycler view.

In order to have a grid of items you need to use a **GridLayoutManager** with span count (number of item per row). In the example below I use 5 items per row:

```
RecyclerView.LayoutManager layoutManager = new GridLayoutManager(this, 5);
recyclerView.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);
```

[documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/GridLayoutManager)

Second, you don’t need to ser the layout manager twice. If you set a layout manager in the **onCreate** of the activity, there is no need to set it also in the **onResponse** callback.

Comment: when i run in memu, my app force close

Answer (score 0):

Set an empty adapter first, update it as soon as you have the data. 
In `OnCreate()` method, add below lines:

```
ArrayList<GudangModel> initialList = new ArrayList<GudangModel>();
mAdapter = new GudangAdapter(MainActivity.this, initialList);
LinearLayoutManager llM = new LinearLayoutManager(MainActivity.this);
recyclerView.setLayoutManager(llM);
recyclerView.setAdapter(mAdapter);
```

And call `notifydatasetchanged` of mAdapter in `onResponse` callback.